# how many time is used to upload a song

Tags: networking, upload

I am new to computer networks and I can not find the solution to 
this problem: If the song of length 4 minutes(4Mbyte)is uploaded with a connection of 1Mbit(744 Kbit upload and 256Kbit upload) in server.
How many time is needed to upload that song?Can somebody tell me if there exists any formula to compute this cuz I am not understanding!!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get a rough answer is to note that 1 megabyte is 8 megabits. We know that the song is 4 megabytes, thus about 32 megabits. You have a (roughly) .75 megabit upload speed, so 32 / 0.75 is about 42 seconds.

Note that other things such as start/stop bits and the actual protocol used can alter the result. This is just a rough calculation only, not exact.